# when i am using sqlite3 with tkinter i am getting Error in create password column

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

In my project, I am creating a Login and Registration form using Tkinter and Sqlite3 I am getting Error in Query .

```
def database():
name1 = Fullname.get()
email = Email.get()
passData = Password.get()
gender = var.get()
country = c.get()
prog = var1.get()
conn = sqlite3.connect('Form.db')
with conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (Fullname TEXT,Email TEXT,Password TEXT ,Gender TEXT,country TEXT,Programming TEXT)')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Student (FullName,Email,Password,Gender,country,Programming ) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',
               (name1, email, passData, gender, country, prog))
conn.commit()
```

Error Message:

```
File "C:/Users/JMD1/PycharmProjects/BugFreeRam/registrationFor.py", line 44, in database (name1, email, passData, gender, country, prog)) sqlite3.OperationalError: table Student has no column named Password
```

Comment: File "C:/Users/JMD1/PycharmProjects/BugFreeRam/registrationFor.py", line 44, in database
    (name1, email, passData, gender, country, prog))
sqlite3.OperationalError: table Student has no column named Password

Comment: Please edit your question to show the error message instead of using a comment. Comments can be deleted at any time, so all important information needs to be incorporated into the question itself.

Comment: I've added the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because you are using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. Which means you already created `Student` table before without `Password` column.

Drop the `Student` table first then re-create it.

Another option is altering the table to add `Password` column.

```
cursor.execute("alter table student add column 'password' 'text'")
```

Comment: Hi @rammohandubey, looking at your question history, I've noticed you haven't accepted an answer in any of your questions. If/when an answer solves your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course, **There is no obligation to do this.**